# Class J RF Power Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, rf, bandwidth, efficiency, configuration

What is a Class-J Amplifier configuration?

Does it work in a push-pull configuration similar to an A/B?
How is it physically different to an A/B?
Where can I see a basic schematic?

I have read through the literature on IEEE Xplore on the efficiency of Class-J amplifiers over wide bandwidth; but I still cant understand how the configuration actually works.

Comment: An answer to this question would require at least one book to write. I doubt that you did not understand anything about it, so what about you ask some more concrete question about a specific aspect?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Ok.. "Does a Class J amplifier work in a push-pull configuration similar to an A/B?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, class J has a single transistor, just as class B amplifier + crazy RF magic to increase efficiency. This paper is pretty clear about it:

> A class-J amplifier is biased as a conventional “deep” class-AB PA
>   that will be considered hereafter in the analytical development as
>   class-B. Thus, a class-J PA demonstrates very similar drain current
>   waveform to its class-B counterpart.

[Integrated Design of a Class-J Power Amplifier by S Rezaei](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/FM_Ghannouchi/publication/258793565_Integrated_Design_of_a_Class-J_Power_Amplifier/links/0f31752e07f98a35e7000000.pdf)

This paper also contains schematics, if you are curious.